# Configuration for multiple databases with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

A Rails 7.0.3 application has the following database.yml configuration, with the default block generated by the rails app initialisation process.

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  primary:
    database: user_development
    username: deploy_root
    password: password
    host: "localhost"
    migrations_paths: db/user_migrate
  primary_replica:
    database: user_development
    username: deploy_readonly
    password: password
    host: "localhost"
    replica: true
  forum:
    database: forum_development
    username: deploy_root
    password: password
    host: "localhost"
    migrations_paths: db/forum_migrate
  forum_replica:
    database: forum_development
    username: deploy_readonly
    password: password
    host: "localhost"
    replica: true
  office:
    database: office_development
    username: deploy_root
    password: password
    host: "localhost"
    migrations_paths: db/office_migrate

test:
  <<: *default
  primary:
    database: user_test
    username: deploy_root
  primary_replica:
    database: user_test
    username: deploy_readonly
  forum:
    database: forum_test
    username: deploy_root
  forum_replica:
    database: forum_test
    username: deploy_readonly
  office:
    database: office_test
    username: deploy_root

  <<: *default
  primary:
    host: 'primary.domain.ws'
    username: deploy_root
    password: [omiss]
    database: user_production
    pool: 50
    timeout: 5000
  primary_replica:
    host: 'replica.domain.ws'
    username: deploy_readonly
    password: [omiss]
    database: user_production
    pool: 50
    timeout: 5000
    replica: true
  forum:
    database: forum_production
    username: deploy_root
    password: [omiss]
    host: 'forum.domain.ws'
    migrations_paths: db/forum_migrate
  forum_replica:
    database: forum_production
    username: deploy_readonly
    password: [omiss]
    host: 'forumreplica.domain.ws'
    replica: true
  office:
    database: office_production
    username: deploy_root
    password: [omiss]
    host: 'office.domain.ws'
    migrations_paths: db/office_migrate
```

However, upon running `bin/rails db:create` the application complains

```
no implicit conversion of nil into String
Couldn't create '' database. Please check your configuration.
```

The syntax is that used in other rails 7 apps, albeit not in partnet/replica contexts and [seems to respect the rails guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_multiple_databases.html#setting-up-your-application) guidelines.

What is wrong with the above that a string get interpreted as nil?

**update**
If the development block is altered to

```
development:
  <<: *default
  database: office_development
  username: deploy_root
  password: password
  host: "localhost"
  migrations_paths: db/office_migrate
  primary:
    [...]
```

the default database is created, but not the main and replicas.  thus there is an issue with the YAML structure, although it lints successfully.

Comment: I'm not a YAML expert, but are you sure that the section after the `test` block is correct?  You seem to be redeclaring the `:primary` databases and all the others, are you maybe missing a `production` label?

Comment: No, there is a production block.  The problem was in invoking the default attributes. + another minor hangup for tests.  Odd, I have not seen documentation on this point.

Comment: yaml is correct but rails expects a nested config structure with multi db set up. move `<<: *default` under `primary` and `primary_replica` etc. each db should have a full definition. yaml's `<<` only keeps you from repeating the same config 20 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call to shared attributes `<<: *default` needs to be removed.
This will allow processing of development databases.

The attributes

```
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
```

being added to each block.

An additional hang-up was with the test databases, the replicas:

```
  primary_replica:
    database: user_test
    username: deploy_readonly
  forum_replica:
    database: forum_test
    username: deploy_readonly
```

needed removing for the process to complete. *I surmise that there is the assumption that objects being read from the main copy is the exact same as it being read from the replica and thus this is excessive*